# How can you ignore google tracking when "do not track" flag is set by browser?

Tags: javascript, privacy, do-not-track

What is the best practice for honouring, via Javascript, the DNT flag set in modern browsers?

Ultimately, I want to disable the likes of Google Analytics, Facebook pixel and other bespoke tracking codes if it is set.

Are there any gotchas to be aware of?

Comment: i'm guessing its up to those service providers to respect those.

Comment: @DanielA.White No it is not.

Comment: it comes as a header on the request to the page - so you'll have to do something on the server side i think

Comment: @DanielA.White No. You can also read it on the client and disable tracking there. Google/Facebook/others mostly just ignore the `DNT` header.

Comment: @DanielA.White I'm assuming they won't honour it, so my plan is not to send information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read the flag using `navigator.doNotTrack` and conditionally load those trackers.

For Google Analytics, you could use the following code:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script>
    if (navigator.doNotTrack !== '1') {
        (function () {
            var ga = document.createElement('script');
            ga.type = 'text/javascript';
            ga.async = true;
            ga.src = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-ADD-YOUR-ID';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag() {
            dataLayer.push(arguments);
        }
        gtag('js', new Date());
        gtag('config', 'UA-ADD-YOUR-ID');
    }
</script>
```

(Also replace `ADD-YOUR-ID` with your actual ID.)

### Resources

- [MDN: DNT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/DNT)
- [MDN: `Navigator.doNotTrack`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/doNotTrack)